# How to get latitude and longitude from google map api using go language?

Tags: json, go, struct, get, unmarshalling

How to get **'lat'** and **'lng'** from **location** in geometry using go language ?

I'm trying to get latitude and longitude to use it for next api to fetch weather of specific location.

I am getting an error when running the code:

> panic: runtime error: index out of range

My response looks like this:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start

My code is here.

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "log"
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
)

const helloMessage = "Hello to the weather program. Please enter the name of the city and the weather will show."
const googleApiUri = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=MYKEY&address="



type googleApiResponse struct {
    Results Results `json:"results"`
}

type Results []Geometry

type Geometry struct {
    Geometry Location `json:"geometry"`
}

type Location struct {
    Location Coordinates `json:"location"`
}

type Coordinates struct {
    Latitude string `json:"lat"`
    Longitude string `json:"lng"`
}


func main() {
    fmt.Println(helloMessage)

    args := os.Args
    getCityCoordinates(args[0])
}

func getCityCoordinates(city string) {
    fmt.Println("Fetching langitude and longitude of the city ...")
    resp, err := http.Get(googleApiUri + city)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Fetching google api uri data error: ", err)
    }

    bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Reading google api data error: ", err)
    }

    var data googleApiResponse
    json.Unmarshal(bytes, &data)
    fmt.Println(data.Results[0].Geometry.Location.Latitude)

    fmt.Println("Fetching langitude and longitude ended successful ...")
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5ANM.png)

Comment: Please add the response to the body of the question, since links may get broken someday...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `float64` to umarshal the latitude and longitude. Since they are not strings. Hence showing error when unmarshalling. Change `Coordinates` struct to

```
type Coordinates struct {
    Latitude  float64 `json:"lat"`
    Longitude float64 `json:"lng"`
}
```

Check working code on [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/VsJ42viGuQX)

For more information on Umarshal along with types that can be used. Go through Golang Spec for [JSON unmarshal](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal)

You can also use `interface{}` if you don't know the format of your struct.

> To unmarshal JSON into an interface value, Unmarshal stores one of
>   these in the interface value:

```
bool, for JSON booleans
float64, for JSON numbers
string, for JSON strings
[]interface{}, for JSON arrays
map[string]interface{}, for JSON objects
nil for JSON null
```

Comment: You were right, they were not strings. Iv found another issue. I should use args[1] not args[0]. After this change + yours change program works fine.

Answer (score 2):

call the [google-maps-services-go](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-go) directly:

```
var clinetGCM *maps.Client
    if clinetGCM == nil {
    // Pre-declare an err variable to avoid shadowing client.
    var err error

    clinetGCM, err = maps.NewClient(maps.WithAPIKey("api-key"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("maps.NewClient failed: %v", err)
    }
}

//CM is a google cloud maps
type CM struct {
  Client *maps.Client
}

// Location is a gps
type Location struct {
  Lat float64 `json:"lat"`
  Lng float64 `json:"lng"`
}

// GeocodeAdress provided Location data from gcp maps geocoder api
func (cm *CM) GeocodeAdress(address string) (Location, error) {

  var loc Location

  r := &maps.GeocodingRequest{
      Address: address,
  }

  res, err := cm.Client.Geocode(context.Background(), r)
  if err != nil || len(res) == 0 {
      return loc, fmt.Errorf("res Geocode err: %v", err)
  }

  loc.Lat = res[0].Geometry.Location.Lat
  loc.Lng = res[0].Geometry.Location.Lng

  return loc, nil
}
```